# Is it bad form to add a tag for synonym purposes?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There is a workable [actionscript-2](/questions/tagged/actionscript-2), and a less descriptive [as2](/questions/tagged/as2) tag.  A synonym proposal does exist, but is lacking in votes, and I currently have not answered enough as2 tagged questions to aid the cause.

Is is considered bad form to add the as2 tag to actionscript-2 tagged questions that I have answered in order to gain voting privileges? Should I maybe just raise the issue here to try and get the synonym voted on instead?

Comment: Yes, that would be bad form. Raising the issue here is the correct thing to do. Either users with voting privileges will jump on the synonym, or a moderator will come along and insta-click it into action.

Comment: I thought it might be, but I have an inherent dislike of troubling people to do something I could maybe do myself.

Comment: @Cody, Are you really very worried about it, though?  If it's not descriptive enough, then surely it will be downvoted.

Comment: @千里ちゃん: I'm not sure I understand... You can't vote on tags themselves. And yes, proposed tag synonyms can be downvoted, but I think this is a *good* suggestion. I don't know anything about Actionscript, so I don't have any rep in that tag and therefore can't vote on the synonym myself, but I wouldn't want to downvote it either. The point is that raising the question here on Meta is exactly what you're supposed to do. There are *tons* of other questions here with the [tag:tag-synonyms] tag.

Comment: @Cody - if you find any of my answers in this tag acceptable you could vote for them. I currently need 3 more upvotes before I can vote on the synonym. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:665800+[as2]

Comment: Well, I would, but my policy is not to vote on answers about things which I know nothing about. That seems unfair to me. And Actionscript is one of those things that I know *nothing* about. I wouldn't know a good answer if it was right in front of my face.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would say that _all_ my answers are excellent, but I don't like to lie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's bad form to do so because if you don't like the tag, then you shouldn't add it to various places throughout the site.  If asking about it here will help just as much, then I think it was a good idea to post here.

Comment: My plan had been to only add it for as long as it took to become a synonym, at which point I guessed it would automatically have been removed. Posting here first was correct though, so I'll wait for kind people with greater powers than I to help out.

Comment: Well, if you're going to do that, then you should at least make sure you don't delete the actionscript-2 tag or any other tags the OP felt were relevant.  If that were the case, then I suppose it wouldn't matter one way or the other.  So, if cody feels strongly about it, he should quickly add lots of a2 tags, so he can eventually get rid of them.